# Getting Single Domain Class Object Without Using GET or LOAD

Tags: hibernate

Hi i have a little doubt regarding Hibernate.
Suppose I want to get specific column from Domain class obj.
Like

```
SELECT i.firstProperty, i.secondProperty FROM Users i WHERE i.id=10
```

And this must return a single obj **not a list**. I can use **GET** or **LOAD** to do this but now I don't want. So is there any other way to do.
I can't use **query** though it has methods which return **list** and I think **QBC** has also **list** having return types. So is there any possible way.

My Code It's generating query successfully but displaying null while calling getProperty.

```
Query query= null;
    DTO dto= null;
    SessionFactory factory= ht.getSessionFactory();
    Session ses= factory.openSession();

    query= ses.createQuery(get_Some_coloumn).setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(MobileBrands.class));

    MobileBrands brands= (MobileBrands) query.uniqueResult();


    System.out.println(brands.getId()+" "+brands.getName()+" "+brands.getPrice());
```

Console
---------------

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        mobilebran0_.BRAND_ID as col_0_0_,
        mobilebran0_.NAME as col_1_0_,
        mobilebran0_.PRICE as col_2_0_ 
    from
        MOBILE_BRANDS mobilebran0_ 
    where
        mobilebran0_.BRAND_ID=5
0 null 0
```

Comment: Does `SELECT i.firstProperty, i.secondProperty FROM Users i WHERE i.id=10 LIMIT 1;` help or is this about how to map those two properties to a single object?

Comment: if you don't want to use `Query` API then `Criteria` API can also help. Use `uniqueResult()`

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow my question is if we want to retrieve one record such as one user details then we have methods like **ses.save(class,id)** and **load** but if the same thing I want to do by passing a query. Is there any way

Comment: @Amogh Criteria Api is 100% hibernate code how can I pass Query I'm aware about **getUniqueResult()** and **getSingleresult()(javax.persistence)** but is there any way to select specific property of a **User.class** by passing query. **Get** and **Load** method will give me all the property colomn. It's fine but for knowledge purpose can I get specific proprty of Only **ONE** user by passing query

Comment: @RiaMohanty are you creating `SQLQuery` using `session.createSQLQuery()` method?

Comment: @Amogh No I have doing like this `ses.createQuery(String query)` but the problem is to execute this query I need `query.list()` which return's a list. But since I'm expecting only one Object of User.class the why I go for List Collection. So I'm stuck in middle. Can u give me a possible hint how can I get Single Object of My User.class by passing query only not by get or load

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown your full code to fetch results so, by some basic considerations I will suggest as:

```
SQLQuery qry = session.createQuery("SELECT i.firstProperty, i.secondProperty FROM Users i WHERE i.id=10")
                      .setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(Entity.class));    
entity = qry.uniqueResult()
```

This will transform SQL result into `Entity`. Just give it a try.

Comment: man it's working but displaying the result **0 null 0** while calling getter property. I have edited the question with code please have a look. I'm using **ORM** So i'm working with **HibernateTemplate(ht)**